# Activiti Java Service Task: Passivate w/out the need for receive task

Tags: scala, asynchronous, task, activiti

this has already been answered but the solutions have not been working out for me.

Activiti asynchronous behaviour is fairly simple and only allows the user to enable a flag which tells activiti engine to insert such task in a execution queue (managing a pool of threads).

What i want is not to insert my java service task in a pool but to passivate its behaviour and only complete such task when an external signal is received and/or a callback is called.

My attempt:

```
class customAsyncTask extends TaskActivityBehavior {
  override def execute(execution: ActivityExecution): Unit = {
    val future = Future {
      println(s"Executing customAsyncTask -> ${execution.getCurrentActivityName}, ${cur}")
    }

    future.onComplete {
      case Success(result) => leave(execution)
      case _ => // whatever
    }
 }
  def signal(processInstanceId : String, transition : String) = {
    val commandExecutor =      main.processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration.asInstanceOf[ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl].getCommandExecutor
    val command = new customSignal(processInstanceId, transition)
    commandExecutor.execute(command)
  }

}
```

On my previous code sample i have registered a scala future callback which when called will terminate the current activity and move to the next.

I also have a signal method which builds a custom signal that based on the processId and a name will call execution.take with the appropriate transition.

On both cases i am getting the following error (the bottom stack changes a little)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:453)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:431)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:47)
```

Unfortunately, it is highly likely that the engine is erasing the information concerning the execution when the execute method returns, even though no complete/leave/take has been called. Even though my callback has the execution object in context, when i query for information using its proccess ID all i receive is null.

So, what i am doing wrong here? How can i achieve the behaviour that i want?

Comment: And to further clarify this is where it is returning null both using runTimeManager directly or a customSignal:

val execution = commandContext.getExecutionEntityManager.findExecutionById(executionID)

Comment: So it seems that it is the EntityManager that no longer holds my execution context

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anything specific, I would have said you need to extend a class that implements SignalableActivityBehavior, but I think TaskActivityBehavior actually does this.

While the stack indicates the NPE is coming from the leave(), I am confused why leave is calling "take" since take is a transition event and really should only happen on a task labeled as synchronous.

All I can offer is, Camunda have an example implementation that is similar to your scenario. You may be able to use this to help you:

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/servicetask/service-invocation-asynchronous

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems that activiti uses thread local variables which means that when calling methods from the scala threads (scala Executor Context) would be pointless since they do not share the context. I will post my solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems that activiti uses thread local variables which means that when calling methods from the scala threads (scala Executor Context) would be pointless since they do not share the context.

To solve all i have to do from my callback is make a signal call much like if i were calling from a remote system. The only difference is that i do not need to save my process instance identifier.

The code looks as such:

```
class AsynchronousServiceTask extends AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior {

  val exec_id : String = "executionId"

  override def execute(execution : ActivityExecution) = {
    val future = Future { println("Something") }

    future onComplete {
      case _ => myobject.callSignalForMe(execution.getId)
    }
  }

  override def signal(execution : ActivityExecution, signalName : String, signalData : AnyRef) = {
    println("Signal called, leaving current activity..")
    leave(execution)
  }
}
```

Basically, myobject holds the runTimeEngine and will inject the signal in a ThreadLocal context. All clean and working as intended.